# Django with Pandas accessing ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, pandas

I do not know Pandas so this may be trivial.

I have this line of code:

```
admin_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(administrations.values()).rename(columns = {'id':'administration_id', 'study_id': 'study_name', 'url_hash': 'link'})
```

which is getting data from the `administration` model (`administrations` is a recordset) and using it.  Rather than using `study_id` I would like to get the study name.  With Djano ORM I would use `study__name` but I cannot do that here.

How can I get the `study.name` instead of `study.id` into `admin_data`?

**models**

```
class administration(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey("study") # Study name
    ...

class study(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51) # Study name
    ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Query the columns you need](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) and use [the `__` syntax to get the name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) through the foreign key:

```py
admin_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    administrations.values(
        "id",
        "study__name",  # <-- get the name through the foreign key
        "url_hash",
    )
).rename(
    columns={
        "id": "administration_id",
        "study__name": "study_name",
        "url_hash": "link",
    }
)
```